# "Experimental support" error while generating migration typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

While trying to run `migration:run` for my nestjs project on typeorm, I get error :

```
error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this 
warning.
```

Whilst I have `"experimentalDecorators": true,"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` configured on my `tsconfig.base.json`. Ps. Although im not sure if typeorm is reading it. I've tried setting the same arguments on `tsconfig.json` as well but no luck.

I also have `experimentalDecorators` setting enabled in VSCode.

my `ormconfig.ts` is as follows:

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm";


const ormconfig: DataSourceOptions = {
    migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
    type: 'postgres',
    url: "SOMEURL",
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    migrationsRun: true,
    entities: ['./apps/api/src/models/interval.entity.ts'],
    migrations: ["./apps/api/src/db/migrations/*.ts"],
    // subscribers: ['./apps/api/src/subscriber/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
};

const ormDatasource = new DataSource(ormconfig);

export default ormDatasource;
```

my sample `interval.entity.ts` is as follows:

```
@Unique('appid_constraint', ['application'])
@Entity({ name: "interval" })
export class IntervalEntity {

    constructor(id: string, appid: string, sent: boolean, time: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.appid = appid;
        this.sent = sent;
        this.time = time;
    }

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "bigint" })
    id: string;

    // join to application
    @OneToOne(() => ApplicationEntity, application => application.intervals)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "application_id" })
    application: ApplicationEntity;
    @Column({ name: "application_id", type: "number" })
    appid: string;

    @Column()
    time: number;

    @Column()
    sent: boolean;
}
```

and my `migration:generate`:

```
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d ./apps/api/ormconfig.ts",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate ./src/db/migrations/$npm_config_name"
```

The issue looks to be occurring since later cli releases. I searched all possible Github and stackoverflow pages but no luck. [This](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6298) looked the most relevant page although I didn't quite catch the solution.

Extended explanation:
`typeorm:0.3.10 | node:16.13.1`
Since my initial commit a year ago, nest built the main configuration on `tsconfig.base.ts`. However, ive heard this file happened to be deprecated for a while now, but still my nest compiler tends to work just fine with that.

my project structure is as follows:

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ apps/
│  ├─ client/ *ignored
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ tsconfig.app.json *extends tsconfig.json
│  │  ├─ tsconfig.json *extends tsconfig.base.json
│  │  ├─ ormconfig.ts
├─ package.json
├─ tsconfig.base.json
```

Note that all initial configurations are in `tsconfig.base.json`. any other tsconfig extends it.

Comment: Mind sharing more details on the versions, what compiler you're using, etc. ?
Also, how is your project structured, it may all be solved by placing your tsconfig on the root of the project.

Comment: @Akheloes Hey! thanks for your answer, i added to my explanation in the ending. i think this is where im lacking but im genuinely lost.

Comment: Let's maybe take a look into those tsconfig files, and while at it, how about you put some very random stuff inside those just to make sure the complier breaks down, that's one way to determine if they are read at all.

Comment: @Akheloes yea im certain its was tsconfig path problem. i think its being read now but still, i get error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`. i do use ts-node, and my entities are ts :`entities: ['./apps/api/src/**/*.entity.js']`. Its just error after error giving me headaches

Comment: Try and push a github repo with the minimum replication, it might just be easier if we could run the issue ourselves.

Comment: @Akheloes i solved the issue. the first problem was the whole structure were false and cli only respected `tsconfig.json` and `ormconfig.ts` in root directory. so a quick reposition did the job. the second and main issue was my `"module":["esnext"]`, changing it to `commonjs` solved it. thanks!

Comment: ok, job well done! Please do put an answer on your thread or think about deleting it if you deem an answer unnecessary :) !